# Add an ImageView behind an "Include" item in XML

Tags: java, android

I have a horizontal scroll of a couple images. I have it in its own XML file that handles just the scrolling, now I want to add an image (Which shouldnt be the size of a background) behind these scrollable items so that the image is visible between and behind the scrollable images?

How can I go about doing this?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp">


<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/dotw_scrollable"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have to add the background programatically as this is a dynamic image

Comment: In your root layout set the image as the background.

Comment: If i do that, it will stretch the image and its not what i want. The image is about quarter the size of the screen. I dont want the image to take up the whole screen, Plus i would like to have a different background for the rest of the Activity

Comment: In that case, could you be clearer about what exactly you want to achieve? Could you provide a screenshot showing what your UI looks like at the moment?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh i did say in my question that it shouldnt be the size of the Background. I will get a screen shot of what i want

Comment: can you can post your layout xml file?

Comment: Please see changes as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout to something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView>
    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/dotw_scrollable"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when i tried this the first time, i was making the background of the "dotw_scrollable" the image, what i have done is brought it into a new xml, and set the adjustViewBounds to true as it made it the size of the screen even though it was set to wrap_content.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :)